# Does useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy work in class library projects?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mixed-mode, fileloadexception

My project setup looks like this:

My application (4.0) --> My class library (4.0) --> 3rd party library (2.0.50727)

My application's app.config looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Yet when trying to launch the application, I receive the dreaded FileLoadException:

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

The respective third-party library is "System.Data.SQLite" v1.0.60.0. Is it necessary to enable the "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" attribute for my class library as well? How would I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help and best regards

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime) help?

Comment: according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/clr/thread/96f90e54-7b7a-4697-9d5e-caa0a15f7425) thread, you don't need to add it to more than the application app.config.

Comment: class libraries don't get their own `.config` files - the only one that matters is the one for the main assembly.

Comment: @Default Nope, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by now. I did not copy the resulting .exe.config file along with my .exe -.- ... Entirely my fault, sorry about this.