# Reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime outside a Web or Worker role

Tags: c#, azure, dll, azure-role-environment

I have a scenario where I need to be able to use the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` outside of a Web/Worker role.

Specifically I have the following code

```
public static RoleInstanceEndpoint ResolveIP()
{
    if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
    {
        RoleInstance instance = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance;

        RoleInstance RelatedWCFInstance = RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyServiceRoleName"]
                                                            .Instances
                                                            .Where(o => o.UpdateDomain == instance.UpdateDomain)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (RelatedWCFInstance != null)
            return RelatedWCFInstance.InstanceEndpoints.Where(o => o.Value.Protocol == "tcp").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code successfully executes when running inside the `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart` event but when I try to execute this code in a separate exe that is ***triggered via Azure startup tasks*** like this

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="StartupMagic.exe" taskType="simple" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

I receive the following error

`The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception.`

Could someone please confirm if it is infact possible to reference this library outside of a Web or Worker role? and if so provide any advice on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Comment: Good question, give me a minute to redeploy and check...

Comment: Well done! "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

Comment: So I take it, its just a matter of doing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime and deploying it with my project

Comment: yes, the referenced question will definitely solve your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the innerException resulted in showing the following message:

"Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

and the solution described in [Mixed mode assembly is built against version ‘v2.0.50727′ of the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime) worked to resolve this problem.