# Mixed mode assembly cannot be loaded

Tags: .net

All my projects are setup to use .net 4.5.1
The test project uses some SQl Server assemblies targeting.NET v2.0.50727.

App.config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime  version="v2.0.50727"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>   
</startup>
```

I also checked this thread among others:
[Mixed mode assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime)

Comment: For all who downvoted, better provide a solution instead of downvoting!
Or leave a comment as suggested, when you downvote!

Comment: (*I'm not a downvoter.*) Presumably the app.config is copied to the build output folder and (say your startup assembly is `ass.exe`) present as `ass.exe.config`.

Comment: It's set to "Do not copy", only the exe.config is in the bin and configured as above mentioned....hm. 
The project in which the error occurs is a c# test project.
It happens when api code from Microsoft.SqlServer*.dll is accessed. Theay are compiled on .NET v2.0.50727.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the startup element didn't do it for me, I went along with the following approach:

[Detailed explanation](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/)

Use the following helper class:

```
using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static class RuntimePolicyHelper
    {
        public static bool LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully { get; private set; }

        static RuntimePolicyHelper()
        {
            ICLRRuntimeInfo clrRuntimeInfo =
                (ICLRRuntimeInfo)RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject(
                    Guid.Empty,
                    typeof(ICLRRuntimeInfo).GUID);
            try
            {
                clrRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
                LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = true;
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                // This occurs with an HRESULT meaning 
                // "A different runtime was already bound to the legacy CLR version 2 activation policy."
                LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = false;
            }
        }

        [ComImport]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        [Guid("BD39D1D2-BA2F-486A-89B0-B4B0CB466891")]
        private interface ICLRRuntimeInfo
        {
            void xGetVersionString();
            void xGetRuntimeDirectory();
            void xIsLoaded();
            void xIsLoadable();
            void xLoadErrorString();
            void xLoadLibrary();
            void xGetProcAddress();
            void xGetInterface();
            void xSetDefaultStartupFlags();
            void xGetDefaultStartupFlags();

            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            void BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
        }
    }
```

And before you call the SMO stuff, just check that everything is ok

```
if (!RuntimePolicyHelper.LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully)
                throw new Exception("Could not load SMO");
```