# Use Old .net dll inside Modern .net application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a .net dll file called `PcapNet.dll` this file is a wrapper around C++ `WanPacket.dll` library.

But `PcapNet.dll` built with `.net3.5`,
every time I reference it in modern .net application `eg, .net 4.7`

Shows me this message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.'

Then I added

```
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v2.0"/>
```

to `App.config`.

And This shows me the next message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PcapNet.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)'

Then I Changed TargetFrameWork to `3.5`. And Now Everything worked correctly. And I Can use it.

But this is a big problem I can not stick with `.net 3.5` I need `4.7` because I will use it in `wpf` application.

So how can i use this legacy library `3.5` with modern .net `4.7`.

Notice: I do not have the source code of this library, I can only access the `dll`.

Comment: Are you compiling your app in 32 or 64 bit mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixed mode assembly is built against version ‘v2.0.50727′ of the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Solved The Problem.